# Remove extra spaces when new items are added to array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

My question is related to a demo that lets me add items to an array and remember them using a session.

I am certain that the extra space is not caused by the `<br />` in my `for` loop. I've tried implementing this with a CSS template, and there's a superfluous empty `<div>` so I'm quite sure that the code is creating an extra value in there.

Any help?

**DEMO**
http://query.notesquare.me/

**CODE**

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input-create-playlist" placeholder="Playlist Name" name="create_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" id="button-create-playlist" value="Create Playlist" />
</form>

<?php
    ini_set("session.save_path", "/home/kucerajacob/public_html/play.notesquare.me/sessions");
    session_start();

    $create_playlist = $_POST['create_playlist'];

    $_SESSION['user_playlists'][] = $create_playlist;

    $playlists = array("One", "Two", "Three");

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['user_playlists']); $i++) {
        array_unshift($playlists, $_SESSION['user_playlists'][$i]);
    }

    $_SESSION['main'] = $playlists;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlists); $i++) {
        echo $playlists[$i] . "<br />";
    }
?>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Check out the demo, I'm trying to have people be able to add items to the playlist cleanly without extra spaces every now and then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" id="input-create-playlist" placeholder="Playlist Name" name="create_playlist" />
    <input type="submit" id="button-create-playlist" value="Create Playlist" />
</form>

    <?php
        ini_set("session.save_path", "/home/kucerajacob/public_html/play.notesquare.me/sessions");

        session_start();

        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
            $create_playlist = $_POST['create_playlist'];

            $_SESSION['user_playlists'][] = $create_playlist;
        }

        $playlists = array("One", "Two", "Three");

        if (isset($_SESSION['user_playlists'])) {
             for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['user_playlists']); $i++) {
                array_unshift($playlists, $_SESSION['user_playlists'][$i]);
            }
        }

        $_SESSION['main'] = $playlists;

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($playlists); $i++) {
            echo $playlists[$i] . "<br />";
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The script runs when you load the page, so it inserts a playlist name that is empty because the text box is empty when the page is loaded. If you add `value="Awesome Playlist"` to your text box element, it will help illustrate what is happening.

Comment: Nope, it works now... You were probably viewing when I was changing the path to my main sessions save folder, but now works! Thank you! +oli-soproni-b